# Augment imported typescript module interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to specify some overrides for events that will give me type safety in an electron app.

For my types:

```
export type SectionName = 'webview'
  | 'index'
  | 'settings'

export interface ShowSection {
  key: SectionName,
}
```

I want to augment this code:

```
import {
  ipcMain,
} from 'electron'

ipcMain.on('rendered', (event) => {
  const sender = event.sender

  event.sender.send('show-section', {
    key: 'index',
  })
})
```

The sender is of type `Electron.WebContents` which is defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/electron/index.d.ts#L4601)

I've tried to augment like this:

```
declare namespace Electron {
  interface WebContents extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
    send(channel: 'show-section', arg: ShowSection): void;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this so that I can get type safety on individual events.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to augment the `WebContents` interface is:

```
declare global {
    namespace Electron {
        interface WebContents extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
            send(channel: 'show-section', arg: ShowSection): void;
        }
    }
}
```

After this you will see the overload options over the `send(...)`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

You can put this on your declaration file (e.g. custom-typings.d.ts):

```
export interface ShowSection {
    key: SectionName
}

export type SectionName = 
    'webview'
    | 'index'
    | 'settings'

declare global {
    namespace Electron {
        interface WebContents extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
            send(channel: 'show-section', arg: ShowSection): void;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks that worked. Unfortunately the side effect i was hoping for, errors if i didn't have correct value for arg don't work, and i'm unsure of if possible.

Comment: I've read the docs a bunch but can't quite figure out where to put a declaration like this in my code. Where can i put the file and how do i configure my compile options to see it?

Comment: The problem with the original `event.sender.send(...)` is that it's accepting `any` as the type of the second argument, so every other types different of your augmentation statement will work. About the module augmentation , you can create s specific file for this (e.g. custom-typings.d.ts). Are you having errors with this?

Comment: where do i put that file to get it to load properly? No error logs per-se, just not getting loaded at all.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a small github repository to show you how to setup this.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help you. I just created this repo https://github.com/Diullei/stackoverflow-43193844 it's working to me, I hope it works to you too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139878/discussion-between-tal-and-diullei).