# How to augment interface with specific overload when it has a catch all?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a method overload signature in an interface from an `npm` package that defines several specific signatures and then a catch-all signature, but my overload doesn't get picked up when I write a call that should match it; the catch-all gets picked up instead. It *seems* to be order-related (though of course I could be wrong), as though the catch-all is getting checked against the call before my new overload is and since it matches, is being used. How can I get my overload to be picked up?

- I've ensured that I'm extending the right interface.
- I've "proven" the catch-all is the problem by commenting it out in the original module's types — when I do that, my added overload gets picked up where it didn't before. (And then if I also comment out my overload, the call shows as an error because nothing matches.)
- I've checked that I'm not hitting the max number of overloads. There are only six originals, plus my addition would be seven; [a quick check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwFgAoZC5OACgHsQIAuZEAVywCNoBKZtz6AG4ylKnQZ92XKABpkYAO61JAqLxZShIyjXpMNquYuUHpRgBZQI+-tPW2t5HeJubZ8pSrPzL1r9DkYWlYofzUw4ScKXQlTAI8TB3cwX1dDZCCQsMDgADc0uwjtaJdshLKUqwL4zNC49xg86vcAZ2B0MPs3SNEY5qNPeosqstrRprK2jqHkFoh8kE6iqLE9CsGk4b8ZsZ2JmanJ+YhFmYhgAHNzMCX6nuc1meMK1NHgus2M-c-Dg+PTz7nK43GYgUDNLqqe4lR6fZ5PV47d7jfKTdpHBZlIHXMpg2Jwk63JLQ1b4twDRLknwjJFZPaog7ov6Ys6XHGg8EVQlnAgspKQ6QkvrrSnpSrbT67SXfKm-H7-LFskGfPH9eTcwG8jVUxQQPAM-nLXqlJ4bHWIyXI+lquWyhWs4G4zlPbXpPX2uEKPUG83AKCQV2FO7FUlq+Fwi1UqVRmXpW1xj1U7HKqmqrkApNajNir36sPmP0B7PeWpFondEPC02i7zitXR9KNH1xpnyvlJpVOsliwPxd3tnPe-OF6zFmrvMt7GCTw3BlZVz01+J1t506XN7zxzeJt2djnd2u99z9o8DIcvEenjIT0fjae3xnoGduAWOY2wnVmsWRxtW9c21s7QHbxky7MMrxPMdklzDdlwLf0H0tEJn0bYB7yvKYUO3BYsJ4I0HgPZcv1rH8Sz-GNYNaQCE2Avs9xVZ0CSguRIPWc8EUvZjr2QxCY3QrjMN4miTlw48lSEoNiUrE1FxeGkkI+CiAOmNsIPo1NGJ1CCszYvMLwQq9Swkmo0NEuRBIw-4zOQZNjPcVVRNfKAhRkz8l2SUjxzXJS0RUoC1MdfdwK41jTXYiNONXAyuMafjfOsuYcLsljxKvBzko8ESAE9yyhaSP3SAA6YqsFoKwwgAbQAXScyIAF8yDIAATCAEDwOArGQAgwBs5gMGwfAIEiMgEHoFoepAZAAF4QwgQqaAARm4ZAAGpZvm6gFrkAAmZa1pWObFp2uQAGY9vWo7kG2065AAFnOg6Nq2q6buQW65AAVge0RDs247kBOu7PrkAA2b7KF+57roBoHkA+0G5AAdnBihIf+wG3uB5AQaRuQAA4UZsp70dh+Hsdx5A8bkABOQm0ZemHMbhhHkER-GabkBaAAY6eJhmMfe5nydZ9nkGpzmuc5pbVouv7+dJlm2cpjnkG5qXOd2mXHsu6GBaxnGReVsWJfV1XoYWs6tZ+vndYV4Wlap43Vcl1XnoW82MYW+6rYhm3XsFsmDYdlW1ddjXOc9wWFq+n3Ub9xmA8V0Xxed033Yjzmo7Jhawdjomdf9-WKcdlPQ4Wt2Pczzns4Nhbkbz+nbaZwPi5Dl3y-D1XI+rzna6VhaCYb+O9aFoPk5NsOzYz1Ws97zn+8dhbaaHguE6Lw2S4njup67qvVZr+fOcXlPtp5le5abxP7fH1PJ-T3eZ571W+6PzmT5d7alsiIA) suggests the limit is much higher than that.
- I've checked that if I set aside my `.d.ts` file for a moment and add my new overload directly to the original interface, above the catch-all, it works. *(Thanks for [that suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73090669/how-to-augment-interface-with-specific-overload-when-it-has-a-catch-all?noredirect=1#comment129089500_73090669), Eldar)*
- I've tried referencing my `.d.ts` file explicitly in `tsconfig.json` (though I suspect that doesn't make sense).
- I've tried referencing my `.d.ts` file via a triple-slash reference directive (though I suspect that doesn't make sense).
- I've tried both of the above with a simple `.ts` instead (though I suspect... ).
- I've looked at various questions about augmenting interfaces ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262565/how-to-augment-typescript-interface-in-d-ts), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196107/augmenting-an-interface-that-lives-in-a-declared-namespace-in-typescript), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817060/augmenting-existing-interfaces), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193844/augment-imported-typescript-module-interfaces), and others), but couldn't figure it out based on them.

This is meant to be a general question, but a specific example helps focus the question and possible answers: The specific case is lodash's `extend` method.

In `@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts`, `extend` is defined like this:

```typescript
declare module "../index" {
    // ...lots of other stuff...

    interface LoDashStatic {
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource>(object: TObject, source: TSource): TObject & TSource;
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2;
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3;
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3, source4: TSource4): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4;
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject>(object: TObject): TObject;
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TResult>(object: any, ...otherArgs: any[]): TResult;
    }

    // ...lots of other stuff...
}
```

As you can see, there are various overloads with specific numbers of source objects, and then a "catch-all" at the very end using rest syntax.

Through machinations in `@types/lodash/index.d.ts` that I frankly don't understand, apparently that `LoDashStatic` interface ends up in the namespace `_`, which is where we see it when using it.

I wanted to add an overload that accepts five source objects rather than topping out at four (as an example for my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089832/). So in a `lodash-extensions.d.ts` file, I did this:

```typescript
declare namespace _ {
    export interface LoDashStatic {
        tjc(): number; // ** I'll explain this below
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4, TSource5>(
            object: TObject,
            source1: TSource1,
            source2: TSource2,
            source3: TSource3,
            source4: TSource4,
            source5: TSource5
        ): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4 & TSource5;
    }
}
```

Then in `test.ts`, I have:

```typescript
import { extend, tjc } from "lodash";

const n = tjc();
console.log(n);
const fourSource = extend({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 });
console.log(fourSource);
const fiveSource = extend({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }, { f: 6 });
console.log(fiveSource);
```

The `tjc` there and in my `lodash-extensions.d.ts` is just to check that I'm augmenting the right interface. It would appear so, since TypeScript is happy with the import and the type of `n` is `number`. (Naturally, if I actually ran this code, that wouldn't work — I haven't implemented `tjc` anywhere.)

In the above, the type of `fourSource` is what you'd expect, it's picking up the four-source overload from lodash's types and so `fourSource`'s type is a union of those source object types (and the `{}` target). The type of `fiveSource` is `unknown`, though, because (apparently) it picks up the catch-all `extend` at the end of the original module's definition, not my added overload, and since I haven't provided a type argument for `TResult` it's had to punt on the inference.

If I go into `@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts` and comment out the catch-all, my new overload gets picked up just fine. This is my "proof" (such as it is) that the catch-all is getting in the way.

I can't think of a way of setting this up in the TypeScript playground (or, of course, on-site Stack Snippets), but I've done a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rzmyvh?file=test.ts) with the code above, or of course if you create a project with TypeScript, install `lodash` and `@types/lodash`, and then drop the `lodash-extensions.d.ts` and `test.ts` files above into it, it should replicate the problem locally.

I can think of a number of workarounds, like declaring my own `extends` that is really just a reference to lodash's and specifying the overloads. But is it possible to add my overload so it gets picked up when using `extends`, and if so, how?

Comment: Did you try injecting your override before the catch-all override in the original source? I suspect the problem is caused by the order of the functions. (There is a reason that catch-all is placed at the bottom) When you are augmenting interfaces typescript is not providing a way (or a rule) that places your override somewhere between the other overrides.

Comment: @Eldar - Yes, as I mentioned, I think it's an ordering issue too. Good point about trying injecting my definition into the `object.d.ts` file in `@types/lodash/common`, just to rule out some issue with my definition. I did that, and it gets picked up as you'd expect. More evidence for the order theory. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: I think typescript guys should invent a decorator that notifies that function has a catch-all signature and it should always be placed at the bottom when the declarations are merged.

Comment: The [docs state](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) that declarations merged later should have higher precedence than earlier ones. I wonder if it also somehow involves the (chronological) order in which the definitions are loaded into the compiler. 

Comment: @jsejcksn - That section is very interesting, thanks!

Comment: Also: I know that you want a generically-applicable solution to the problematic behavior described in your question (and I know there are many "workarounds"), but, if you need compiler safety right now, you can just alias/bind the method to a local variable with your own (asserted) signature(s).

Comment: @jsejcksn - Indeed. As you said, though, I'm interested in finding out whether what I'm trying to do can be done. And I'm nagged by the idea that I'm Just Doing It Wrong. :-D

Comment: @jcalz - I tried on codesandbox and gave up with bizarre errors. I'll try stackblitz.

Comment: @jcalz - stackblitz was dead easy by comparison (once I got my browser's ad blocking out of the way; for some reason it interfered with starting a new project): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rzmyvh?file=test.ts Updated the question.

Comment: So, I don't really understand why you're doing `declare namespace _` using namespaces when the code you care about is doing `import` using modules.  I have no idea how your version is doing what it's doing, but if I were going to try to merge into a module I'd use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) as shown [in this version of the stackblitz project](//stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hms8w2?file=lodash-extensions.d.ts,test.ts).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what goes wrong?

Comment: @jcalz - Oh, I tried lots of stuff, the `declare namespace _` version was where I ended up and it *seemed* to do the job since `tjc` was there and my overload was there when I commented out the catch-all. In fact, I even tried `declare module "lodash"` at one point, but with no luck -- I'm guessing because I didn't have that `import`. Yes, that absolutely works. Unless there's a better version of this question that already exists, would you post an answer? And thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) says you should use `declare module` for this purpose:

```
declare module 'lodash' {
  export interface LoDashStatic {
    extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4, TSource5>(
      object: TObject,
      source1: TSource1,
      source2: TSource2,
      source3: TSource3,
      source4: TSource4,
      source5: TSource5
    ): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4 & TSource5;
  }
}
```

That would work just fine if you put it in the same file where you use lodash.  But if you want to put it in its own file by itself, then you will run into the annoying issue that the compiler will interpret it as a new [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) instead of modifying an existing imported module.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#49227](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49227).  So if you want to do this in a separate file, that file should have at least one top-level `import` or `export`:

```
import 'lodash'; // or whatever 
declare module 'lodash' {
  export interface LoDashStatic {
    extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4, TSource5>(
      object: TObject,
      source1: TSource1,
      source2: TSource2,
      source3: TSource3,
      source4: TSource4,
      source5: TSource5
    ): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4 & TSource5;
  }
}
```

You can see this in action in [this version of the stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hms8w2?file=lodash-extensions.d.ts,test.ts).

Comment: Thanks! That was one of the many things I tried but without the all-important `import`/`export` (and then the namespace thing was the one that at least *seemed* to be doing something). *"So if you want to do this in a separate file, that file should have at least one top-level import or export:"* Just to (as it were) augment that: It could be just `export {};` ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vavnle?file=lodash-extensions.d.ts)). But I like your import "lodash";, given what the file is doing. :-)